# Flutter: Firebase DebugView Unreliable Analytics Event Logging

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

I have enabled the debugview and analytics for my flutter application. I have also created a logEvent to capture GestureDetector taps. Unfortunately it seems like the debugview for firebase is very unreliable and only SOME of the tap events come through. Is debugview just unreliable? Or is there a method to capture events that are frequent, such as button pushes/GestureDector taps?

Event capture:

```
 Container buildShopCards(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            //doc = all store details
            logAnalytics.buttonPushed(
              docId: doc.documentID,
              buttonName: doc.data['name'],
              currentPageName: StorePickerRoute,
            );
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, StoreDetailsRoute, arguments: doc);
          },
          child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            color: widgetDecoration.offWhiteColour,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    AutoSizeText(
                      '${doc.data['name']}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23.0),
                      minFontSize: 15,
                      maxLines: 1,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

logEvent function:

```
void buttonPushed({String docId, String buttonName, String currentPageName}) {
    //remove '/' from route name
    currentPageName = currentPageName.substring(1);

    analytics.logEvent(
      name: 'button_pushed',
      parameters: {
        //can't have '/' from route names in the values. Need to remove
        'store_doc_id' : docId != null ? docId : "null",
        'button_name' : buttonName != null ? buttonName : "null",
        'origin_page' : currentPageName != null ? currentPageName : "null",
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your `buttonPushed` function is not async, however the `logEvent` method is. So maybe the resulting blocking operation might be the cause for not recognizing any further taps.

Comment: @PaezRice Thanks. I did try async (with everything), but it still results in some sort of clash since only one, two, or none will go through to the debugview if multiple buttons are pushed over a short period of time.

Comment: Yeah, rethinking my comment from before, I realized, that there isn't any heavy blocking operation going on, since your function is sync and only calls an async one and therefore returns just after this is call. So sorry for wasting your time there.

Comment: I've spent days debugging this with same issue. I see logcat output on Android as well as console logs from iOS that shows the event being sent. My next step is to verify that I see it on the wire by doing a network trace.

Comment: I have the same problem, I have a funnel with 7-8 button to push and I hardly have a time in which they are all logged together in the debug view. The log tell the upload is successful but nothing appear. Do you maybe had some success in the last months?